# AngularJS typeahead directive - get result on select?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I have been trying to implement a bootstrap Typeahead element in my angular project but the examples provided here are pretty complicated and I can't quite parse which of these attributes controls how the tabbing on a matched entry or clicking on the list in the dropdown triggers the model update.  After adapting the typeahead example on [this page](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) to my model, the popup appears correctly, but clicking on the list or tabbing on a partial match does not populate my input element as it does in the example.

Here are the html elements for the input and the list I have been using.

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="customPopupTemplate.html">
  <div class="custom-popup-wrapper"
     ng-style="{top: position().top+'px', left: position().left+'px'}"
     style="display: block;"
     ng-show="isOpen() && !moveInProgress"
     aria-hidden="{{!isOpen()}}">
    <p class="message">select location from drop down.</p>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="listbox">
      <li class="uib-typeahead-match" ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }"
        ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index)" role="option" id="{{::match.id}}">
        <div uib-typeahead-match index="$index" match="match" query="query" template-url="templateUrl"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</script>

<div class='container-fluid typeahead-demo' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">

<p>{{items.length}}</p>
    <h4>Custom popup templates for typeahead's dropdown</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{myCell.value + "/" + myCell.entry + ' selected: ' }}{{selected}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="myCell.entry" ng-keypress="checkEntry($event, myCell.entry)" placeholder="Custom popup template" 
    uib-typeahead="name   as item.name for item in items | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-popup-template-url="customPopupTemplate.html" typeahead-min-length="0" class="form-control">
    <label id="value">{{myCell.value}}</label>
  </div>
```

Which part of this need to be modified so that selecting on the list or pressing tab on a partial match in the input box populates the input box and updates the model attribute 'myCell.entry'?

Also how is the selectMatch function called in the custom-popup-wrapper ng-click attribute `ng-click="selectMatch($index)" implemented?`   The js file provided with the sample has no implementation code the scope, and there's nothing in the documentation other than the code about it.